# Including dummies with respect to dates

Tags: r, dataframe

Let's consider data following

```
df1<-data.frame('firm'=c(rep(1,3),rep(2,4)),'year'=c('1901','1902','1903','1900','1901','1902','1903'))
df1
firm year 
1    1901
1    1902
1    1903
2    1900
2    1901 
2    1902
2    1903
```

I want to include three level dummies with respect to year i.e. first dummy should start from the earliest data point. I mean it should look like following :

```
firm year dummy_1 dummy_2 dummy_3
1    1901   0       1        0
1    1902   0       0        1
1    1903   1       0        0
2    1900   1       0        0 
2    1901   0       1        0
2    1902   0       0        1
2    1903   1       0        0
```

Please notice that first dummy starts as (0,1,0) because 1901 is second to the earliest date point. Also notice that firm two start from (1,0,0) because 1900 is the earliest data point.

I started with changing years vector to vector which stores information about occurrence in time. i.e.

```
as.numeric(as.factor((df1$year))) 
2 3 4 1 2 3 4
```

And now I wanted to change

```
2 to (0,1,0)
3 to (0,0,1) 
4 to (1,0,0)
1 to (1,0,0)
```

However I don't how to do it actually. Am  I thinking correctly about implementing these dummies ?

Comment: Smallest year for firm 1 is 1901 and not 1900?

Comment: Yes it's 1901 and that's the tricky part of the problem - that for certain firms starting year may vary

Comment: So shouldn't the first row be (1,0,0)?

Comment: No, because (1,0,0) is reserved for the earliest year in data set which is 1900

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need a modulus operation here, starting with the minimum year and moving forward from there.

```r
mtx <- matrix(0, nrow=nrow(df1), ncol=3)
mtx[cbind(seq_len(nrow(mtx)), 1 + (as.integer(df1$year) - min(as.integer(df1$year))) %% 3)] <- 1
colnames(mtx) <- paste0("dummy_", 1:3)
df1 <- cbind(df1, mtx)
df1
#   firm year dummy_1 dummy_2 dummy_3
# 1    1 1901       0       1       0
# 2    1 1902       0       0       1
# 3    1 1903       1       0       0
# 4    2 1900       1       0       0
# 5    2 1901       0       1       0
# 6    2 1902       0       0       1
# 7    2 1903       1       0       0
```

This operates on the assumption that the years are contiguous; if there is a gap and you need the gapped year to not count, then we'll need a slightly different approach.

```r
mtx <- matrix(0, nrow = nrow(df1), ncol = 3)
years <- unique(sort(df1$year))
years
# [1] "1900" "1901" "1902" "1903"
mtx[cbind(seq_len(nrow(mtx)), rep(1:3, length.out = length(years))[ match(df1$year, years) ])] <- 1
colnames(mtx) <- paste0("dummy_", 1:3)
df1 <- cbind(df1, mtx)
df1
#   firm year dummy_1 dummy_2 dummy_3
# 1    1 1901       0       1       0
# 2    1 1902       0       0       1
# 3    1 1903       1       0       0
# 4    2 1900       1       0       0
# 5    2 1901       0       1       0
# 6    2 1902       0       0       1
# 7    2 1903       1       0       0
```